# Can we create Materialized view from view with force and editionable options in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle. I am using oracle database 19c. I try to create a materialized view from a view. But i get "ORA-00942" error. Does this mean a mview cannot be created from a force editionable view or it is possible to create with any additional privileges? Thanks in advance.

```
sql>conn kish/password
Connected.
sql>create table ds as select * from dba_source;

Table created.

sql>create or replace force editionable view "dsv" as select * from ds;

View created.

sql>create materialized view dsmv as select * from dsv;
create materialized view dsmv as select * from dsv
                                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"dsv"` is different from `dsv`. In Oracle, **never** use double quotes (unless you have a really, really good reason - and this isn't one).

Remove double quotes, entirely.

```
SQL> create view dsv as select * from dept;

View created.

SQL> create materialized view dsmv as select * from dsv;

Materialized view created.

SQL> select * from dsmv;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: I am able to create mview from normal view. But if i provide options "editionable" and "force", i get ORA-00942

Comment: Yes, oracle consider special characters as case sensitive. I am able to create mview using quotes.                                                                                               
                     sql>create materialized view dsmv2 as select * from "dsv";

Materialized view created.

Comment: Yes, you can create a materialized view if you enclose view name into double quotes, but that's **bad practice** as far as Oracle is concerned. You'll **always** have to remember that you created that view using lower case letters, enclosed into double quotes - and **reference** that view exactly that way, every time. BAD practice. As I said: remove double quotes, entirely.